# Create array of Google Drive File Names

Tags: google-apps-script

I can send an email with one pdf attachment.

```
function send_email() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('MEMBER');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email Template');

var subject = sheet2.getRange(7,1).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(7,2).getValue();

var n=sheet1.getLastRow();

for (var i = 3; i < n+1 ; i++ ) 
{

var EmailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,5).getValue();


let message2=message.replace("<Member>",Member);

 var file1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('pdf1.pdf');
 var file2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('pdf2.pdf');


MailApp.sendEmail(EmailAddress, subject, message2,{
     
       name:"Iceman",
       attachments: [file1.next(), file2.next()]});

}
}
```

However, I'm having difficulty placing the two pdfs (file1 & file2) into an array, to be able to send two attachments.

I'm not very well versed in this language.

Can anybody help me place two Google file names into an array?  SO I can use an array for the attachments.

Thank you

Comment: I have tried your script and it works on my side. The test email I got had two PDF files attached. Is it possible that there is one PDF file on your side which is non-existent causing your automated email to only send one PDF file?

Comment: Well, the script works when in the app script editor.  However, When I attach the script to a button in my Google Sheets,- I get an error: Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.

it doesn't like the .next.. SO I think I need to place these into an array. But Im having trouble doing so correctly.

Comment: I attached the script to a button on my sample sheet. It still worked. The line `attachments: [file1.next(), file2.next()]});` is already in array form. Anyway, are you able to share a sample spreadsheet so that the community may look further into your issue?

Comment: The only error that I encountered was in the line `let message2=message.replace("<Member>",Member);` since `Member` is undefined. I just replaced it with a random string.

Comment: You all are correct.  It was a user rights issue having access to that particular file.  I appreciate your time.  Thank you